# Angular JS - Get the controller instance or instantiate a controller via code

Tags: angularjs

in Angular JS world the controller of a component gets initialized when it gets called. So typically we would register our component with module

```
angular.module('moduleName').component('componentName', { //code })
```

and then we call our component like

```
<componentName></componentName>
```

My question is can we get the controller instance like as we get for services ?

```
injector.get('serviceName')
```

I need invoke or access my component controller methods programatically before it gets called like this.

```
 <componentName></componentName>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide more details about the higher level problem you are trying to solve. Currently your question is too vague

Comment: Each component initialise its own controller. So you can not access component controller before it is initialised.  Services are singletons, components behave different and have their own life cycle.

Comment: Actually my use case is similar to " $controller('testController', {$scope: this});". This the code which will return us an controller instance registered with angular.module(''xxx').controller('xxx'). Similarly, I need to get an component controller instance which is registered as angular.module(''xxx').component('xxx', { 'controller: function(){}'})